# JSDoc multiple key value pair generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, .d.ts

How can I add multiple key value pairs to a function call similar to the way `document.createElement` works (`<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(tagName: K): HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]`)

This is only so that the JSDoc is properly setup and VSCode intellisense picks up on it and works appropriately.

Map declaration:

```
export interface KeyMap {
  "A": "true" | "false";
  "B": "a" | "b" | "c";
  "C": "foo" | "bar";
}
```

Function declaration:

```
export interface Options {
  [key: keyof KeyMap]: KeyMap[key];
  // It's not working since I don't have a way to refer to the generic type of the key
}

export function test(options: Options);
```

Calling the function

```js
test({ "A": "true", "C": "bar" });
```

Since it's on a key and value basis, I don't know how to add a generic so I can later get the possible values for each key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using `{ [K in keyof KeyMap]: KeyMap[K]; }` and using a `type` instead of an `interface`

```
export type Options = {
  [K in keyof KeyMap]: KeyMap[K];
}
```